# KDTree double type integers

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kdtree

I have a list of 2 dimensional coordinates that I am creating a `kdtree` from. The coordinates are of type `double`- e.g. `[508180.748, 195333.973]`

I use numpy to create and array and I then use scipy's KDTree functions.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial

points_array = np.array(points)
kdt = scipy.spatial.KDTree(points_array)

# Query    
tester = kdt.query_pairs(20)
tester = list(tester)    
print(tester[0])
```

This returns:

`(109139, 109144)`

The result has lost the resolution of the original data. How do I keep the double precision floating point format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the indices in the array of points, not coordinate values of the points themselves. The tuple has two indices, one for each point in the array that is part of a pair whose separation in your coordinate space is less than the query distance.

To see the values of the coordinates of the points in your pair, you could do the following:

```
tester = kdt.query_pairs(20)
tester = list(tester)    
print(points_array[tester[0][0]], points_array[tester[0][1]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and it returned `(array([ 527948.,  169578.]), array([ 527959.,  169593.]))` Why is it dropping anything past the `.` ?

Comment: I get the full precision when I use this code, so I'm afraid I don't know why you are seeing this behaviour. My guess is those values did not have anything after the `.` or you have some other issue, perhaps something to do with `dtype`. You would have to post the traceback for someone to help you troubleshoot.